# how to check user permissions in snmpv3

Tags: snmp, router, cisco, cisco-ios

we have a cisco router, which configured with SNMP v3 and username is `testAdmin`. Is there any command to identify, whether this user has read-only permission or read-write?

Regards,
Sumesh.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to write down the config with the community which you have.

http://www.ciscozine.com/how-to-save-configurations-using-snmp/

This will not affect any service and will prove you if the string is working.

The other option is to bring up loopback interface with some random number